# ggplot - stat_smooth - linear model on log-transformed data - plotting on non-log scale

Tags: r, logging, ggplot2, lm

I did a lm on log-transformed data, and plotted it with ggplot :

```
myplot <- myplot + stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x)
```

Here is my figure: 
[image]

So I'm happy with that, but now I want to come back on my un-logged data and plot it. Here is my figure:
[image]

My question is: How can I add my model to this figure? Because my model is a linear regression on log-transformed data, but now I'd like to plot it on my non log-transformed diagram.

Thanks in advance to those who can help me.

Comment: Not sure about that, but probably `myplot + stat_smooth(method="glm", formula=y~x, family=quasi(link='log'))` is the thing you are looking for?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the exact same query

Comment: @tonytonov your suggestion to use the family function is the correct answer. Thanks for that. Of note, this does not work for methods other than lm and glm. I had a similar issuing and nls model and ended up having to modify the formula  of the equation directly to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could un log your predicted values from the model output by raising to power 10.

i.e.

```
10^(y)
```

this would transform your predicted values back to actual data as opposed to the log equivalent. you can then plot this new back-transformed data

Comment: But what about the variance?